# vba inserting/copying range of rows next cell formulas collapse

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, insert

i am using basic vba code to insert `Range(C3:E3").Insert xlShiftDown` rows. I discovered that, formulas which are related to these cells, and are in different columns also collapse with inserting range.row (not entire.row).
I wonder if there is any workaround with vba code(i mean using insert with different mode) or it is part of excel game we need to figure out to solve our problem without inserting rows.
Appreciate any guidance or opinion why it could be so in excel ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try cut or paste?

```
Range("C3:E3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C10").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Range("C3:E3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C10").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: In second splee of your code `Range("C3:E3").Select
Selection.Cut` are you cutting the blank rows? Why?

Comment: I have used also `Range(oneColumn & rowToCut & ":" & secondColN & m).Cut Destination:=Range(oneColumn & rowToPaste)` cut it similarly moves down formulas

Comment: same with your code, just moves down let's say if you have in your example formulas in F3 column which has C3 or D3 or E3, he formula in F3 changes to C10,...